# EZAudio output source is not consistant ? and EZAudio Plot Mirror Not Consistant?

Tags: objective-c, ezaudio

Its taking random output source, some time uses the phone hearing speaker some times loud speaker.

I implemented the EZAudioPlotGL,sometimes only the top part of it is showing , even though shouldMirror is set to YES at all times. Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used "EZAudioPlot.h" class rather than "EZAudioPlotGL.h". which resolves issue of inconsistent wave form.

and implemented clear method in "EZAudioPlot.m" class because it does not have implementation or clear method.

```
  -(void)clear
{
    float              empty[_changingHistorySize];
    // Figure out better way to do this
    for(int i = 0; i < _changingHistorySize; i++ )
    {
        empty[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < _scrollHistoryLength; i++)
    {
        _scrollHistory[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    _scrollHistoryIndex = 0;

    [self setSampleData:_scrollHistory
                 length:(!_setMaxLength?kEZAudioPlotMaxHistoryBufferLength:_scrollHistoryLength)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. Although the app will crash if you try to call clear method before there is any plot done. So just place this check if(_scrollHistory == NULL)  return; on start of this method and you are good to go.